# Intel processor still running after shutdown

Tags: cpu, asus-laptop, ubuntu-16.04

These are my laptop's specs:

- ASUS F550J
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4720HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
- Motherboard:

  - 64 architecture
  - Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
  - Product Name: X550JX

When I'm shutting down the laptop via OS shutdown (from both Ubuntu 16 and Windows 10 - I have them both on my laptop) or via holding the power button for a couple of seconds, the processor is still working and the battery is completely drained overnight.

The processor stops but I think that not completely as I can hear a little noise every 1 second as something inside my laptop is still working. As a remark, this is happening in the majority of cases, but not in all of them.

So this problem is not that my fan is still working or that my leds are turned on, but something else that I cannot find on the internet.

Same thing is happening when I put it on Hibernate with `sudo pm-hibernate`, but it's not on hibernate in any other cases because it's a fresh start after I power it off.

Please let me know what other informations I could provide to this question.

Thanks!

**Update**:

Test after comments:

1. Shut down the laptop
2. Remove any USB
3. Problem still there
4. Go to BIOS to see something about USB charger: nothing

I don't think the Asus USB charger it's active because my mouse does not have any power after shutting down the laptop.

I have this problem for over an year now and I think it was since I first bought the laptop (almost 2 years), but noticed it after a couple of months.

**Update after service:**

The guy that looked at my laptop told me that this is quite usual unfortunately. The reason behind being some software code at a very low level on the motherboard (if I remember correctly) that will start to mess your battery after a while - 2 years or something. He told me that this was intentionally put there by the manufactures - now I don't know if to believe him or not but it fixed the problem.

What they did was to reprogram some part of the motherboard that affects the battery - told me that there is a chance not to fix it. After that it works. Seems something with Intel processors on Asus Notebooks only. Hope it helps.

Comment: Many computers leave certain peripherals powered on, even when shut down, especially USB ports, so that you can continue charging a peripheral while powered off. If you leave USB devices plugged in, they are liable to drain the battery while the CPU is powered off. You may be able to control this within the BIOS firmware.

Comment: What kind of noise is it? Can you see the fan & it's definitely not spinning, or even try removing the hard drive? Only the fan & speakers & a spinning hard drive should be making noise, the only other noises I can think of could be a battery that's really really bad, dangerously bad

Comment: @AFH, please see my update.

Comment: @Xen2050, now that I listen to it again, it is similar to the one made by the DVD writer, but more silently (not used the DVD writer in years). The fan definitely stops. I didn't try removing the hard as I think I still have it's warranty - but I will update you on that soon. You may be right about this being a sound made by the HDD.

Comment: The HD should be removable with only a screw or two, but don't break any "warranty void" type stickers. Whatever it is, if the system's off then everything else should be off too, if there's a system warranty still it might be useful. Or a workaround to remove the battery when off, add a master power switch even?

Comment: It's not just the USB that sometimes retains power when CPU is not running, though it's the most common. Other devices may stay powered, so that they can be used as wake-up devices (LAN, keyboard, etc), but I can't think of any that would emit a sound. Just to make sure you haven't a faulty battery, remove it when you shut down (as @Xen2050 suggests) and check that it has retained its charge when you plug it in again.

Comment: That's true too, my "everything else should be off" wasn't 100% accurate, there's a surprising number of things that aren't really fully "off" and keep listening or charging (& using power), can't help with battery life much